# Ordering the calling of asynchronous methods in c#

Tags: c#, events

Say I have 4 classes

- ControllerClass
- MethodClass1
- MethodClass2
- MethodClass3

and each MethodClass has an asynchronous method DoStuff() and each has a CompletedEvent.

The ControllerClass is responsible for invoking the 3 asynchronous methods on the 3 MethodClasses *in a particular order*.

So ControllerClass invokes MethodClass1.DoStuff() and subscribes to  MethodClass1.CompletedEvent. When that event is fired, ControllerClass invokes MethodClass2.DoStuff() and subscribes to MethodClass2.CompletedEvent. When that event is fired, the ControllerClass invokes MethodClass3.DoStuff()

Is there a best practice for a situation like this? Is this bad design?

I believe it is because

- I am finding it hard to unit test (a sure sign)
- It is not easy to change the order
- I have an uneasy, code-smell feeling about it

What are the alternatives in a situation like this?

Note: I am targeting the .NET 2.0 framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Richter has a great article about using enumerators to simplify APM code. Microsoft CCR also uses a similar technique. Worth investigating:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546608.aspx

Comment: His AsyncEnumerator is a simple version of the Microsoft CCR, which is supersede by the Task Parallel Library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check that out. I should have stated I am targeting .NET 2.0. I'll update my original question.

Comment: @Oliver: as far as I know, task parallel library doesn't supersede the ccr, it can be used side by side and they have different characteristics. Ccr is light weight async processing and messaging, tpl is more heavy duty paralyzing big algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the code of the classes that you are invoking, and also have the freedom to change it, why not wrap it up in a handler (implementing Chain of Responsibility pattern). You can then define successor for each method. That will keep the complexity low with a higher flexibility.

Comment: That's interesting approach actually. I like being able to set the successor in this pattern. +1 there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What version of .NET are we using? In .NET 4.0 there is the Task class which you can use to fire tasks, and change the order very easily.

A good example is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/

You can see how you can queue up tasks.

Comment: This belongs to the Task Parallel Library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: @Oliver: PFX is part of .NET 4.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in doing it this way.  Call *one* helper method asynchronously.  It should call the three methods you are now running asynchronously.  Sequencing them is now simple and you only have one async method to worry about.  More efficient too, you are not starting and switching between threads anymore.  It actually takes *less* time.

Comment: Thanks Hans. So wrap the methods in one async helper method and then let that worry about the ordering of the other 3 methods etc. It would simplify things from the caller alright.

Answer (score -1):

Since the three methods you are using needed to be run in a particular order and they need to wait for each other, why do you bother calling them asynchronously? Just make simple synchronous calls.

Comment: The methods themselves start asynchronous work so they will return to the caller immediately. The only way to know something interesting has happened is to subscribe to the Completed event.

Comment: Perhaps the code is heavily concurrent (on a server?), in which case blocking the thread for any amount of time would be inadvisable as it would require many threads that sit around doing nothing. In my experience, NOT using APM in this situation is a really good way to kill server performance.